# Kettle: Multiple putRows() in processRow() correctly?

Tags: java, normalization, pentaho, kettle

I'm processing a `/etc/group` file from a system. I load it with `CSV input` step with the delimiter `:`. It has four fields: `group`,`pwfield`,`gid`,`members`. The `members` field is a comma separated list with account names of unspecified count from 0 to infinite.

I would like to produce a list of records with three fields: `group`,`gid`,`account`. In the first step I use `User Defined Java Class`, in the second I use `Select values`.

Example Input:

```
root:x:0:
first:x:100:joe,jane,zorro
second:x:101:steve
```

Example output (XLS) - expected:

```
group   gid account
first   100 joe
first   100 jane
first   100 zorro
second  101 steve
```

Example output (XLS) - actual, wrong:

```
group   gid account
first   100 zorro
first   100 zorro
first   100 zorro
second  101 steve
```

User Defined Java Class:

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    // boilerplate
    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }
    String tmp = get(Fields.In, "members").getString(r);
    if(null==tmp)
        return true;
    String accounts[] = tmp.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<accounts.length; ++i){
        Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
        String account = accounts[i];
        get(Fields.Out, "account").setValue(out_row,account);
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I believe that I missed to call some administrative function, or I should use something other than `createOutRow()`. Google did not helped.

[image: Kettle transformation illustration]

Misterously if I create a transformation like the illustrated then

- `XLS debug A` has correct `account` values in each row
- `XLS debug B` has repeating `account` values like the example output.

If I place a `Dummy` step before `Select values 7`, the `XLS debug B` becomes correct and `XLS debug A` becomes bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the following line (first line in the for loop):

```
Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
```

It should be replaced with these three lines:

```
Object[] out_row = RowDataUtil.allocateRowData(data.outputRowMeta.size());
for (int j=0; j<r.length; ++j)
    out_row[j] = r[j];
```

**UPDATE**: A more easy way which is essentially the same:

```
Object[] out_row = RowDataUtil.createResizedCopy(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
```

Comment: thanks! used the "more easy way" and worked like a charm!